# Element does not return to its position CSS Float

Tags: html, css

What happens is that the nav-search-ul element does not return to the correct position after changing screen resolution, it's like the media does not work.

only happens in chrome, since in firefox y IE everything ok

[image]

so you can check in [click](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpOGpe)

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="m">aaaaa</li>
        <li class="nav-search-ul">bbbbb</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    li {
      color: red;
      display: block;
    }

    ul {
      clear: both;
      background: rgb(27, 34, 36);
      text-align: center;
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      li {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .nav-search-ul {
        float: right;
      }
    }
```

**OK solution**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPOGZN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following CSS:

```
.nav-search-ul {
  display:inline  
}
```